# How to disable progress bar in Pytorch Lightning

Tags: pytorch, tqdm

I have a lot of issues withe the  tqdm progress bar in Pytorch Lightning:

- when I run trainings in a terminal, the progress bars overwrite themselves. At the end of an training epoch, a validation progress bar is printed under the training bar, but when that ends, the progress bar from the next training epoch is printed over the one from the previous epoch. hence it's not possible to see the losses from previous epochs.

```
INFO:root:  Name    Type Params
0   l1  Linear    7 K
Epoch 2:  56%|████████████▊          | 2093/3750 [00:05<00:03, 525.47batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=0.714, training_loss=0.4, v_nb=51]
```

- the progress bars wobbles from left to right, caused by the changing in number of digits behind the decimal point of some losses.
- when running in Pycharm, the validation progress bar is not printed, but in stead,

```
INFO:root:  Name    Type Params
0   l1  Linear    7 K
Epoch 1:  50%|█████     | 1875/3750 [00:05<00:05, 322.34batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  50%|█████     | 1879/3750 [00:05<00:05, 319.41batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  52%|█████▏    | 1942/3750 [00:05<00:04, 374.05batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  53%|█████▎    | 2005/3750 [00:05<00:04, 425.01batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  55%|█████▌    | 2068/3750 [00:05<00:03, 470.56batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  57%|█████▋    | 2131/3750 [00:05<00:03, 507.69batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  59%|█████▊    | 2194/3750 [00:06<00:02, 538.19batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  60%|██████    | 2257/3750 [00:06<00:02, 561.20batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  62%|██████▏   | 2320/3750 [00:06<00:02, 579.22batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  64%|██████▎   | 2383/3750 [00:06<00:02, 591.58batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  65%|██████▌   | 2445/3750 [00:06<00:02, 599.77batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  67%|██████▋   | 2507/3750 [00:06<00:02, 605.00batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  69%|██████▊   | 2569/3750 [00:06<00:01, 607.04batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
Epoch 1:  70%|███████   | 2633/3750 [00:06<00:01, 613.98batch/s, batch_nb=1874, loss=1.534, training_loss=1.72, v_nb=49]
```

I would like to know if these issues can be solved or else how can I disable the progress bar and instead, just print some log details on the screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the command `show_progress_bar=False` in Trainer.

Comment: In 1.0.5 this does not work anymore (see answer below)

Answer (score 20):

F.Y.I. `show_progress_bar=False` deprecated since version 0.7.2, but you can use `progress_bar_refresh_rate=0`

---

update:

`progress_bar_refresh_rate` has been deprecated in v1.5 and will be removed in v1.7. To disable the progress bar, set `enable_progress_bar` to false

```
progress_bar_refresh_rate: How often to refresh progress bar (in steps). Value ``0`` disables progress bar.
    Ignored when a custom progress bar is passed to :paramref:`~Trainer.callbacks`. Default: None, means
    a suitable value will be chosen based on the environment (terminal, Google COLAB, etc.).

    .. deprecated:: v1.5
        ``progress_bar_refresh_rate`` has been deprecated in v1.5 and will be removed in v1.7.
        Please pass :class:`~pytorch_lightning.callbacks.progress.TQDMProgressBar` with ``refresh_rate``
        directly to the Trainer's ``callbacks`` argument instead. To disable the progress bar,
        pass ``enable_progress_bar = False`` to the Trainer.

enable_progress_bar: Whether to enable to progress bar by default.
```

Comment: It seems this only work for `trainer.fit`, but not for `trainer.test`

Answer (score 5):

> I would like to know if these issues can be solved or else how can I disable the progress bar and instead, just print some log details on the screen.

As far as I know this problem is still unresolved. The pl team points that it is "TQDM related thing" and they can't do anything about it. Maybe you want to read [this issue](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/765)

**My temporary fix is :**

```
from tqdm import tqdm

class LitProgressBar(ProgressBar):
   
    def init_validation_tqdm(self):
        bar = tqdm(            
            disable=True,            
        )
        return bar

bar = LitProgressBar()
trainer = Trainer(callbacks=[bar])
```

This method simply disables the validation progress bar and allows you to keep the correct training bar [[refer 1](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/765#issuecomment-732510678) and [2](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/765#issuecomment-732510678)]. Note that using `progress_bar_refresh_rate=0` will disable the update of all progress bars.

**Further solution: (Update1 2021-07-22)**

According to [this answer](https://forums.pytorchlightning.ai/t/progress-bar-reprints-during-validation/348/2), the `tqdm` seems to only be glitching in the `PyCharm` console. So, `a possible answer` is to do something with `Pycharm` setting. Fortunately, I find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64727188/8437317)

> 1. Go to "Edit configurations". Click on the run/debug configuration that is being used. There should be an option "Emulate terminal in output console". Check that. Image added for reference.
>    [image]
> 2. Along with the `position` argument also set the `leave` argument. The code should look like this. I have added `ncols` so that the
>    progress bar doesn't take up whole of the console.
>
> ```
> from tqdm import tqdm import time
> for i in tqdm(range(5), position=0, desc="i", leave=False, colour='green', ncols=80):
>     for j in tqdm(range(10), position=1, desc="j", leave=False, colour='red', ncols=80):
>         time.sleep(0.5)
> ```
>
> When the code is now run, the output of the console is as shown below.
>
> ```
> i:  20%|████████▍                                 | 1/5 [00:05<00:20,  5.10s/it] 
> j:  60%|████████████████████████▌            | 6/10 [00:03<00:02,  1.95it/s]
> ```

Follwing the above two steps, we can display the progress bar in the Pycharm in the normal way. To finish the step2 in the `Pytorch-lightning`, we need to override functions *init_train_tqdm(), init_validation_tqdm(), init_test_tqdm()* to change the ncols. Some codes like this (hope it helps):

```py
class LitProgressBar(ProgressBar):

    def init_train_tqdm(self) -> tqdm:
        """ Override this to customize the tqdm bar for training. """
        bar = tqdm(
            desc='Training',
            initial=self.train_batch_idx,
            position=(2 * self.process_position),
            disable=self.is_disabled,
            leave=True,
            dynamic_ncols=False,  # This two lines are only for pycharm
            ncols=100,
            file=sys.stdout,
            smoothing=0,
        )
        return bar

    def init_validation_tqdm(self) -> tqdm:
        """ Override this to customize the tqdm bar for validation. """
        # The main progress bar doesn't exist in `trainer.validate()`
        has_main_bar = self.main_progress_bar is not None
        bar = tqdm(
            desc='Validating',
            position=(2 * self.process_position + has_main_bar),
            disable=self.is_disabled,
            leave=False,
            dynamic_ncols=False,
            ncols=100,
            file=sys.stdout
        )
        return bar

    def init_test_tqdm(self) -> tqdm:
        """ Override this to customize the tqdm bar for testing. """
        bar = tqdm(
            desc="Testing",
            position=(2 * self.process_position),
            disable=self.is_disabled,
            leave=True,
            dynamic_ncols=False,
            ncols=100,
            file=sys.stdout
        )
        return bar
```

If it does not work for you, please update the version of `Pytorch-lightning` to the lastest one.

Comment: Recently, I noticed that [progress_bar_refresh_rate](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common/trainer.html#init) will be ignored when a custom progress bar is passed to callbacks in `Trainer`. So if you want to change the refresh rate of progress bar, please use 'bar = LitProgressBar(refresh_rate=your_refresh_rate)' instead of 'bar = LitProgressBar()'

Comment: Are you using `ProgressBar` instead of tqdm? ```class LitProgressBar(ProgressBar)```. I get ```NameError: name 'ProgressBar' is not defined```

Answer (score 4):

to disable the progress bar pass `enable_progress_bar = False` to the Trainer.

Comment: This is the correct answer in Pytorch Lightning 2.x

Answer (score 0):

If you like to turn off the progress bar, you can use this in Trainer. Setting parameter of "progress_bar_refresh_rate" to 0 will disable the progress bar, however this setting will be omitted if you specify your own progress bar in callback. Note that pl is pytorch lightning module (*import pytorch_lightning as pl*) which may different from your style.

```
trainer = pl.Trainer(..., progress_bar_refresh_rate=0)
```